# How to connect and insert data in database of wordpress?

Tags: database, mysql, wpdb

On my website, there is a section called "My Ideal plank."

It is a form where the user will enter their data and there will be a return message with the type of ideal board for the person.

First step, make the form: Done;

Now do I need to connect and register the data in the database. I created a table in the Wordpress database called "minhaprancha". But I am not able to record the data on it: confused:

The connection code and registration is as follows:

```
<?php
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
require_once('../../../wp-config.php');
global $wpdb;

  $nome = "";
  $email = "";
  $estilo = "";
  $experiencia = "";
  $altura = "";
  $peso = "";

  //VÁRIÁVEIS 
  if(!empty($_POST)){     
     $nome = $_POST['nome'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $estilo = $_POST['estilo'];
     $experiencia = $_POST['experiencia'];
     $altura = $_POST['altura'];
     $peso = $_POST['peso'];


     cadastrar($nome,$email,$estilo,$experiencia,$altura,$peso);
     calcularIMC($estilo,$experiencia,$altura,$peso);

  }


  function cadastrar($nome,$email,$estilo,$experiencia,$altura,$peso){          //INSERE OS DADOS NO BANCO
      try{

         $wpdb->insert( "INSERT INTO aa_minhaprancha("."nome, email, estilo, experiencia, altura, peso) VALUES (". ":nome', ':email', ':estilo', ':experiencia', ':altura', ':peso')");

          if($wpdb->rowCount() > 0)
              return true;
          else
              return false;

      }catch(PDOException $e){
         echo "Erro ao incluir na tabela categoria ".$e->getMessage();
      }
  }

 ?>
```

At first, how can I connect and register the data in the database?

Comment: Have you considered using a custom post type and `wp_insert_post` instead? Then you don't have to write any queries, you can use `WP_Query` to fetch things and gain caching speed ups, and you get a free user interface in the admin area and REST API endpoints!

Comment: Also, don't try to insert standalone files for form processing or AJAX requests, it's dangerous, easy to break, and causes problems

Answer (score 1):

Two things, at least: It looks like you need to declare the `global $wpdb` and you're using `$wpdb->insert()` incorrectly. The `insert()` method doesn't take your SQL query but a list of variables. It then create the SQL for you. See [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row)

You can execute SQL directly but it's a different process.